# Rest Collision Error on in lilypond

Tags: lilypond, engraving

In a project of mine, one of the staves, whenever I put anything in it that isn't a full bar rest throws up a "cannot resolve rest collision: rest direction not set" error. It will still render but it any note written is doubled as you can see below on the third staff from the bottom

[image]

However, when I copy and paste the entire file into lilybin, it works fine with no errors, as you can see [here](http://lilybin.com/8q6db2/2). Is this because I am using some outdated syntax somewhere and lilybin is running an older version of lilypond? The code in the lilybin is exactly copy and pasted from what I am doing in frescobaldi.

The log given by frescobaldi is

> /Users/Jack/Desktop/Sorabji Quintet/Quintet.ly:48:6: warning: this Voice needs a \voiceXx or \shiftXx setting
>
> r8
>
> d''
>
> Finding the ideal number of pages...
>
> Fitting music on 1 page...
>
> Drawing systems...
>
> /Users/Jack/Desktop/Sorabji Quintet/Quintet.ly:48:3: warning: cannot resolve rest collision: rest direction not set
>
> r8 d''
>
> /Users/Jack/Desktop/Sorabji Quintet/Quintet.ly:48:3: warning: cannot resolve rest collision: rest direction not set
>
> r8 d''

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure about the versions (you're correct to say that the older Lilypond won't make the notes appear twice, while the newer does --- you can also try it in Lilybin if you click on the "Stable" button and change it to "Development"), however, you have a simple error in there that explains it. In your piano staff, you have

```
\new Staff = "up" \scoreARight { \clef "treble^8"  \scoreARight }
```

As you can see, the `\scoreARight` variable is put twice into the staff. Just remove the first occurence to make it

```
\new Staff = "up" { \clef "treble^8"  \scoreARight }
```

and everything should be all right. The "cannot set rest direction" warning comes (I would guess) from the fact that the two rests were colliding (one being exactly on the top of the other), and Lilypond couldn't figure a way to resolve the collision (usually based on stem direction, among others).